# Paser XML in python

Tags: python, xml

I am getting this xml response, can anybody help me in getting the token from the xml tags?

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><LoginResponse xmlns="http://videoos.net/2/XProtectCSServerCommand"><LoginResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><RegistrationTime>2018-09-06T07:30:38.4571763Z</RegistrationTime><TimeToLive><MicroSeconds>3600000000</MicroSeconds></TimeToLive><TimeToLiveLimited>false</TimeToLiveLimited><Token>TOKEN#xxxxx#</Token></LoginResult></LoginResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

I have it as a string

Tried lxml and other libs too like ET but wasn't able to extract the token field. HELPPP

Update with a format xml to make you easy to read, FYI.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <LoginResponse xmlns="http://videoos.net/2/XProtectCSServerCommand">
      <LoginResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <RegistrationTime>2018-09-06T07:30:38.4571763Z</RegistrationTime>
        <TimeToLive>
          <MicroSeconds>3600000000</MicroSeconds>
        </TimeToLive>
        <TimeToLiveLimited>false</TimeToLiveLimited>
        <Token>TOKEN#xxxxx#</Token>
      </LoginResult>
    </LoginResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text  = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <LoginResponse xmlns="http://videoos.net/2/XProtectCSServerCommand">
      <LoginResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <RegistrationTime>2018-09-06T07:30:38.4571763Z</RegistrationTime>
        <TimeToLive>
          <MicroSeconds>3600000000</MicroSeconds>
        </TimeToLive>
        <TimeToLiveLimited>false</TimeToLiveLimited>
        <Token>TOKEN#xxxxx#</Token>
      </LoginResult>
    </LoginResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

parser = BeautifulSoup(text,'xml')
for item in parser.find_all('Token'):
    print(item.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `lxml`

**Demo:**

```
x = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <LoginResponse xmlns="http://videoos.net/2/XProtectCSServerCommand">
      <LoginResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <RegistrationTime>2018-09-06T07:30:38.4571763Z</RegistrationTime>
        <TimeToLive>
          <MicroSeconds>3600000000</MicroSeconds>
        </TimeToLive>
        <TimeToLiveLimited>false</TimeToLiveLimited>
        <Token>TOKEN#xxxxx#</Token>
      </LoginResult>
    </LoginResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>'''

from lxml import etree
xmltree = etree.fromstring(x)
namespaces = {'content': "http://videoos.net/2/XProtectCSServerCommand"}
items = xmltree.xpath('//content:Token/text()', namespaces=namespaces)
print(items)
```

**Output:**

```
['TOKEN#xxxxx#']
```

Comment: Thanks. You are a savior \m/